# Twit , media upload directly from a url

Tags: node.js, twitter

I want to download an img from a url and upload it to twitter directly without saving it to a file first.

So far I've tested all of the ways I found online but no luck. I always get "Media type not recognised" error.

```
  http.get("http://localhost:9000/screenshot/capture/" + shot.slug,
          function(response){
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {

      response.setEncoding('binary');
      var imageFile = "";
      response.on('data', function(chunk){
        imageFile += chunk;
      });

      response.on('end', function(){
        imageFile = imageFile;
        // first we must post the media to Twitter
        T.post('media/upload', {media_data: imageFile.toString('base64')}, function (err, media, response) {
          if(err) return console.log("ERRR2: ", err);
          console.log("DATA: ", media);
          console.log("RESPONSE: ", response);
          // now we can assign alt text to the media, for use by screen readers and
          // other text-based presentations and interpreters
          var mediaIdStr = media.media_id;     
          var altText = "Alt text for the shot";
          var meta_params = { media_id: mediaIdStr, alt_text: { text: altText } };
          console.log(meta_params);

          T.post('media/metadata/create', meta_params, function (err, data, response) {
            if (!err) {        
              // now we can reference the media and post a tweet (media will attach to the tweet)
              var params = { status: 'by @' + twitter_handle + ' at ' + "http://localhost:9000/" + shot.slug, media_ids: [mediaIdStr] };

              T.post('statuses/update', params, function (err, data, response) {
                console.log("DATA: ", data);              
              })
            }
          });
        });
      })
      //console.log(image);
    }
```

Twit works. I can send status updates and use the API all the way through. Also I can send media file when I save it to disk first then read it with `fs`. But I want to get it from the url as binary and somehow upload it to Twitter.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to use streams: https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html or more specifically: https://github.com/request/request#streaming

In particular, something like

```
request('http://google.com/doodle.png').pipe(T.postMediaChunked)
```

There's no problem doing an intermediate step of writing to disk though, you just have to handle cleanup after.